# Can I predict different targets and use different features of my saved model?

Tags: python, machine-learning, streamlit

I'm curious if I can load my saved trained model and predict different features and target, is that even possible? or I have to make several models for all the possibilities?

Because I want to deploy ML model into Streamlit web app and users can choose features and target whatever they want, just something like this

[image]

Comment: Looks fairly straightforward. I am not sure what is the issue you are facing here. If you are using saved models, you must train the model with all the possible combinations of the target variable, feature variable, and algorithm. Or, if not all combinations are covered, you can limit the user-tunable parameters according to the models you have trained.  If the data is not that big, you can do the training process on streamlit instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use your saved model for prediction, If you want to move to cloud then you can retrain the model, save the saved model(say h5) in the cloud(say AWS) then you can fetch predictions from in there. Plus it would give you the flexibility to constantly train the model and used the trained model.